# Why don't the pictures change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a function that allows me to display the uploaded image on the website immediately, but it doesn't work. could you help me and tell me what the problem is or what I'm doing wrong? I would be very grateful!

I think the problem is that the function doesn't recognize "this" or something like that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".img-upload").change(function () {
        if ($(this).files != null && $(this).files[0] != null) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('div.img-see-upload').css({
                    'background-image' : 'url(' + e.target.result + ')'
                });
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL($(this).files[0]);
        }
    });
});


<div class="m-3 position-relative">
    <div class="position-absolute m-auto h-100 w-100 center-center" style="left: 0;right: 0;">
        <div class="tutorial-area center-center bg-white border-0 pointer">
            <button>
                <img src="public/assets/img/upload.png" class="loading-logo">
            </button>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="pointer img-upload"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-see-upload background-image-kochstream background-cover" style="background-image: url(public/assets/img/kochen.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `files` property on the jQuery object.... would be `this.files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in the code you wrote

{$ (this).parent().parent().parent ()} **is a big mistake** because it stops with the smallest change

You need to add a class to the **parents div** and use it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".img-upload").change(function () {
     var that = $(this)
        var files = $(this)[0].files
        if (files != null && files[0] != null) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
      
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                that.closest('.parent').find('div.img-see-upload').css({
                    'background-image' :  'url(' + e.target.result + ')'
                });
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.img-see-upload {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-3 position-relative parent">
    <div class="position-absolute m-auto h-100 w-100 center-center" style="left: 0;right: 0;">
        <div class="tutorial-area center-center bg-white border-0 pointer">
            <button>
                <img src="public/assets/img/upload.png" class="loading-logo">
            </button>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="pointer img-upload"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-see-upload background-image-kochstream background-cover" style="background-image: url(public/assets/img/kochen.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use arrow function for event listener like this:

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('div.img-see-upload').css({
                    'background-image' : 'url(' + e.target.result + ')'
                });
            };
```

OR just save the instance:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var self = this;

reader.onload = function (e) {
    $(self).parent().parent().parent().find('div.img-see-upload').css({
            'background-image' : 'url(' + e.target.result + ')'
    });
};

reader.readAsDataURL($(this).files[0]);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the script doesn't seem to recognize the if-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".img-upload").change(function () {
      console.log($(this));
        var input = $(this)[0];
        if (input.files) {
            var reader = new FileReader(),
              imgSeeUploadDiv = $(input).closest('.m-3').find('.img-see-upload')[0];
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              console.log($(this));
                $(imgSeeUploadDiv).css({
                    'background-image' : `url(${e.target.result} )`,
                    "width": "50px",
                    "height": "50px"
                }
              );
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

A few things to notice:

- No need for `!= null`
- The 'this' changes inside 'reader.onload' function.
- Must add 'height' and 'width' to the elements css.
- You can use the '[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)' function to find a specific parent